# How to start redis server and config nginx to run mediacrush script on CentOS?

Tags: python, linux, nginx

I found a MediaCrush open source from here

> https://github.com/MediaCrush/MediaCrush

But stuck in last steps.
I started the Redis server, use command

> $redis-cli

that received the "PONG" response.

Then used the command

> $celery worker -A mediacrush -Q celery,priority

and after

> python app.py

But it seem that nothing works. I just installed nginx, run it on my IP ok, but after edit the nginx.conf like a Mediacrush script, then accessing my IP, nothing happens. 
So what am I missing here? and how to config nginx server and start redis server to run this script on CentOS (i can change it to Arch like them if required)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to run it for fun.. so this may be wrong but what I did after running the celery daemon was edit the app.py script and manually set the host, port, and set debug to false. Then I just executed it like any other python script.

**EDIT**: This may work

```
PORT=8000 gunicorn -w 4 app:app
```

it switches your port to 8000 and runs the gunicron daemon with 4 workers. both approaches worked for me.

**Edit File:** `./app.py`

```
from mediacrush.app import app
from mediacrush.config import _cfg, _cfgi
import os
app.static_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "static")
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # CHANGE THIS LINE TO REFLECT YOUR DATA
   app.run(host=_cfg("debug-host"), port=_cfgi('debug-port'), debug=True)
   # FOR EXAMPLE I CHANGED IT TO THIS
   # app.run(host="92.222.25.245", port=8000, debug=0)
```

Also to start redis i believe you should do `redis-server&` I use the cli to manually tinker with it.

Btw I did this on linux mint / ubuntu 14.04 / debian